# Node.js - how to call a Facebook API within a for loop without exceeding rate limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have an array with almost 2 millions of Facebook idSender, and I want to itearate over it, calling a Facebook API for each one of them.
Now, due to the asynchronicity, if I launch a simple for loop, Facebook would return me a rate limit exceed error after 4-5 minutes.
After some attempts I found out that the ideal delay to avoid rate limit is 20 milliseconds.

So I tried this solution: I wrapped my function in a Promise, and I used setTimeout to set a delay.

```
async function asyncLoop(values) {
  var prm = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            check(values[i].idSender, values[i].iscrizione, values[i].id_sito)
            if(checked == values.length) {
                resolve()
            }
        }
    },20);
  });
  return prm;
}

asyncLoop(idSenderArray)
```

but this solution it's not working, and I'm also aware it's almost never a good idea using setTimeout fuction to manipulate asynchronicity in Javascript, in fact I can't even say what exactly it's happening there.

Any suggestion for possible modifies to my function? Any idea on a totally new implementation that could work?
Thanks

Comment: Try async.eachLimit instead of promises here?  By throttling your concurrent calls instead of the time each call takes, you might achieve the same objective.  https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit

Comment: 20ms delay per 2M items gives you 11 hours 7 minutes of running time. How often do you do this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `await` a time inside the for loop:

```
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function asyncLoop(values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    await timer(20);
    check(values[i].idSender, values[i].iscrizione, values[i].id_sito)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `check` is an asynchronous function, as such I would also suggest making this function promise based, and then also using `await check`, otherwise requests could start interweaving due to network lag etc, and then your back to rate limiting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may also do something like this with promises;

```js
var apiCall = (url,n) => new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v,50,`the result of API call @ ${url} no ${n}`)),
    calls   = Array(20).fill()
                       .map((_,i) => new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v,20*i))
                                         .then(_ => apiCall("http://facebook.com",i))
                                         .then(v => console.log(`I am doing something with ${v}`)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
height: 100%;
max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using setTimeout with promises can also be used:

```
async function asyncLoop(values) {
    let apiCallPromises = values.map((value, index)=> new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(_=>{
            check(value.idSender, value.iscrizione, value.id_sito)
            resolve()
        }, index*20)
    }))

    return Promise.all(apiCallPromises);
}
```

Fairly strait-forward, it maps each value to a `check()` call with a delay of 20n ms for each subsequent request.